# Finding & Evaluating Salesforce Backup & Recovery Service Providers

Tags: metadata-api, data-loader, rollback, version-control, backup

Realize that anything a third-party Salesforce backup & recovery service is able to do in theory I am able to do, but short-term, I am more focused on deploying Salesforce, than recovering it. That said, given Salesforce does not appear to even have a "one-click" backup & recovery feature, I want to know **how to find & evaluate third-party Salesforce backup & recovery service providers**, and any major gotchas to watch out for when using them.

*Please note that this is NOT a request for a list of Salesforce backup & recovery service providers, per [Stack Exchange's shopping recommendation guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce suggestion on the page promoting their own [data recovery service](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003594) (which is a one-time $10K minimum service) is to [query the AppExchange for partners](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=backup) that provide backup & recovery services.

*[Yes. This is an answer to my own question, but attempting to move the ball forward - and get an answer from someone that has a deeper knowledge of the topic.]*